# Random Dungeon/Maze Generator

Tags: tools, tool-recommendation, dungeon, generator, terrain

I'm looking for a good random dungeon/maze generator.  Some key features I'd like it to have:

- Can generate a regular maze (one entrance & exit, even passage width, every spot within the area is reachable)
- Can create rooms within area.  So passage ways suddenly open up to a room/cavern with only a couple entrances and any passages near the room wrap around the area like normal architecture.
- Random doors
- Points of interest (finding a pile of skulls, a water well, generic shrine, etc.)
- Multiple level generator (including stair cases, holes in the floor/ceiling, etc.)
- Being able to choose what features are used in the generation of the map.

Some nice features to have, but not required:

- Secret doors/walls
- Random encounter table
- Treasure tables

Comment: Ahh, yes, once again SE's rules closing highly upvoted (== useful) questions. Good job for keeping the streets safe!

Answer (score 20):

There is [Dizzy Dragon's generator](http://www.dizzydragon.net/adventuregenerator/gen) which has a variety of layouts and is oriented to Moldavy B/x D&D.

There is [Donjon's generator](http://donjon.bin.sh/4e/dungeon/) which has D&D 3.5 and D&D 4.0 options. But the layout are strictly room and corridor.

Both create the encounters for you. Of the two Dizzy Dragon is the best.

Answer (score 13):

You might want [Dizzy Dragon's generator](http://www.dizzydragon.net/adventuregenerator/start). It does encounters and treasure, although no random encounters. The dungeons are generated from geomorphs, so the maps are more complex and interesting than the fully random versions. Each map will have some three dimensionality, with stairs up to some sections and so forth.

Answer (score 4):

My generator doesn't do everything in your list, but what it does it does better than most:
[www.apolitical.info/webgame/dungeon](http://www.apolitical.info/webgame/dungeon/)

Comment: @James: Welcome! Can you explain which things it does do and why it does those things better than most?

Comment: That's a very interesting generator, and definitely filling a different niche than most. Adding a brief overview of its features and design goals would make this a good answer.

Answer (score 3):

Dizzy Dragon is amazing. I’d also recommend using [The Fantasy Oracle](http://crngames.com/oracle) to add an overall theme to the adventure. It provides a handful of adventure elements that make it easier to create a background for the random dungeon.

Comment: Fantasy Oracle looks awesome!  I look forward to using that.